# How to strip/trim characters in command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a bunch of files (around 900) that have some special characters.

Some of the files contains example, and quoting "[useless] filename (something)"
so what I want is just to strip the brackets and parenthesis, some are folders, others are text files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian comes with a program called [`prename`](https://packages.debian.org/source/bookworm/rename) (also known as `perl-rename`) which can rename files using Perl-style regexes:

```
prename 's/^\[.+?\] *//; s/ \(.+?\)$//' *
```

Comment: Use `-v` for verbose and `-n` to preview the results (and do nothing). This way you can check the result first.

Comment: sorry, my regex skill sucks so I ask.. there are some files with brackets parenthesis on both sides, but that code only removes the starting line :(